# Count the number os individuals in a panel and how many times they appear in the panel

Tags: r

I have a panel data in the form of data frame like this
I have many countries and many observations for each one.
My goal is to count the number of countries that appear in the data frame and how many times each country appears

An example of my data frame is below

```
> ff
        cross_id date_id E.tertiary lv18_bank_c
1        Albania    1982    2.13747           0
2        Albania    1984    2.22216           0
3        Albania    1985    1.80637           0
4        Albania    1986    1.82942           0
5        Albania    1987    2.06611           0
6        Albania    1988    3.85074           0
7        Albania    1989    2.89562           0
8        Albania    1990    2.05454           0
9        Albania    1991    2.57309           0
10       Albania    1992    3.84439           0
11       Albania    1993    4.26285           0
12       Albania    1994    3.57016           1
13       Albania    1995    4.90303           0
14       Albania    1996    5.70181           0
15       Albania    1997    5.37198           0
16       Albania    1998    3.95752           0
17       Albania    1999    6.34027           0
18       Albania    2000    8.44206           0
19       Albania    2001   11.10053           0
20       Albania    2002   14.78250           0
21       Albania    2003   15.78137           0
22       Albania    2004   16.72831           0
23       Albania    2005   24.65881           0
24       Albania    2006   26.68887           0
25       Albania    2007   32.61487           0
26       Albania    2008   33.94730           0
27       Albania    2009   33.69017           0
28       Albania    2010   28.62207           0
29       Albania    2011   13.83260           0
30       Albania    2012    7.49656           0
31       Albania    2013   -4.29068           0
32       Algeria    1988    1.94325           0
33       Algeria    1989    1.60497           0
34       Algeria    1991    1.12511           0
35       Algeria    1994    2.73635           0
36       Algeria    1996    5.49956           0
37       Algeria    1997    5.95291           0
38       Algeria    2000    7.14822           0
39       Algeria    2002    7.94752           0
40       Algeria    2004   11.33143           0
41       Algeria    2005   10.74001           0
42       Algeria    2006   10.34123           0
43       Algeria    2007   10.86369           0
44       Algeria    2008   10.28966           0
45       Algeria    2010    6.87194           0
46       Algeria    2011   12.73942           0
47       Algeria    2012   16.43274           0
48       Algeria    2013   19.16414           0
49     Argentina    1981   15.69030           0
50     Argentina    1982   16.11802           0
51     Argentina    1986    2.62316           0
52     Argentina    1995   16.96348           1
53     Argentina    1999   18.52467           0
54     Argentina    2000   15.13495           0
55     Argentina    2001   12.99992           1
56     Argentina    2002    7.40008           0
57     Argentina    2003    5.30822           0
58     Argentina    2004    5.03020           0
59     Argentina    2005    7.74603           0
60     Argentina    2006   12.33073           0
61     Argentina    2007   10.48156           0
62     Argentina    2008   11.81227           0
63     Argentina    2009   12.93886           0
64     Argentina    2010   13.79554           0
65     Argentina    2011   13.98205           0
66     Argentina    2012   13.66112           0
67       Armenia    1987    7.74252           0
68       Armenia    1989    0.32560           0
69       Armenia    1990   -1.35376           0
70       Armenia    1991   -6.26625           0
71       Armenia    1992   -2.63647           0
72       Armenia    1993    8.23146           0
73       Armenia    1994   12.18477           1
74       Armenia    1995   16.42548           0
75       Armenia    1996   14.46316           0
76       Armenia    1997   19.20829           0
77       Armenia    1998   14.49865           0
78       Armenia    1999    4.30956           0
79       Armenia    2000    4.33436           0
80       Armenia    2001    7.56556           0
81       Armenia    2002   12.38564           0
82       Armenia    2003   12.34247           0
83       Armenia    2004   14.11571           0
84       Armenia    2005   15.10601           0
85       Armenia    2006   13.79101           0
86       Armenia    2007    3.04268           0
87       Armenia    2008   -0.19355           0
88       Armenia    2009   -1.40714           0
89       Armenia    2010   -4.81279           0
90       Armenia    2011   -1.90896           0
91       Armenia    2012   -1.08625           0
92       Armenia    2013    8.41245           0
93       Austria    1981    5.33637           0
94       Austria    1982    5.51511           0
95       Austria    1983    6.90563           0
96       Austria    1984    7.59978           0
97       Austria    1985    8.59364           0
98       Austria    1986    9.16943           0
99       Austria    1987   10.90617           0
100      Austria    1988   11.95211           0
101      Austria    1989   12.89434           0
102      Austria    1990   14.38936           0
103      Austria    1991   14.95411           0
104      Austria    1992   14.87273           0
105      Austria    1993   14.78557           0
106      Austria    2008   16.60811           1
107      Austria    2009   13.27180           0
108      Austria    2010   12.60677           0
109      Austria    2011    7.83117           0
110      Austria    2012    6.55769           0
111   Bangladesh    1981    1.73887           0
112   Bangladesh    1982    1.22771           0
113   Bangladesh    1983   -0.08311           0
114   Bangladesh    1984   -1.00364           0
115   Bangladesh    1985   -0.83548           0
116   Bangladesh    2000    0.81326           0
117   Bangladesh    2001    1.72986           0
118   Bangladesh    2002    1.28143           0
119   Bangladesh    2003    2.53967           0
120   Bangladesh    2004    4.46713           0
121   Bangladesh    2006    7.24486           0
122   Bangladesh    2007    6.43980           0
123   Bangladesh    2009    4.98099           0
124   Bangladesh    2012    4.45990           0
125   Bangladesh    2013    6.76407           0
126      Belarus    1981    7.19799           0
127      Belarus    1982    7.01108           0
128      Belarus    1983    7.67367           0
129      Belarus    1984    7.01828           0
130      Belarus    1985    6.93979           0
131      Belarus    1986    3.79298           0
132      Belarus    1987   -1.31170           0
133      Belarus    1988   -3.02827           0
134      Belarus    1989   -5.95809           0
135      Belarus    1990   -7.48738           0
136      Belarus    1991   -4.60565           0
137      Belarus    1992   -2.63166           0
138      Belarus    1993    5.38768           0
139      Belarus    1994    8.98458           0
```

I need to count how many countries appear in this data frame and also the number of how many times they appear.

For example like this:

```
Number of countries - 52
Albania - 30
Algeria - 17
etc
```

Comment: `ff %>% count(cross_id)` using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
table(ff$cross_id)
```

which gives

```
   Albania    Algeria  Argentina    Armenia    Austria Bangladesh    Belarus
        31         17         18         26         18         15         14
```